# How to switch workspaces in Xubuntu by scrolling mouse wheel over the desktop?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, workspaces, workspace-switcher

Back in Debian I used to switch workspaces in XFCE just by rotating mouse wheel while the pointer is on any clear piece of the desktop (one where I can see the wallpaper). But in Xubuntu that doesn't work, the workspaces can be switched only by scrolling over the workspace applet. How can I fix that behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I have found the answer. Settings - Window Manager Tweaks - Workspaces - Use the mouse wheel on the desktop to switch workspaces.